# Compiling error with C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

This is the error and program. I gives me this error, and I cant find any mispelling in main.cpp

**ERROR**

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘int GPIO::unexport_gpio()’:
main.cpp:27:45: error: conversion from ‘const char*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’ requested
  ofstream unexportgpio = (unexport_str.c_str());
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
main.cpp:28:7: error: ‘exportgpio’ was not declared in this scope
  if(!(exportgpio.is_open())
       ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:29:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘return’
   return -1;
   ^~~~~~
main.cpp:30:2: error: ‘exportgpio’ was not declared in this scope
  exportgpio<<this->gpionum;
  ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In member function ‘int GPIO::setdir_gpio(std::__cxx11::string)’:
main.cpp:36:64: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  std::string setdir_str = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio"+this->gpionum;+"/direction";
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:37:41: error: conversion from ‘const char*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’ requested
  ofstream setdirgpio = (setdir_str.c_str());
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:48:2: error: ‘setdirgpio’ does not name a type
  setdirgpio.close();
  ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:49:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
  return 0;
  ^~~~~~
main.cpp:50:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
main.cpp: In member function ‘int GPIO::setdir_gpio(std::__cxx11::string)’:
main.cpp:47:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
```

^

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

GPIO::GPIO()
{
        this->gpionum = "4";
}

GPIO::GPIO(std::string gnum)
{
        this->gpionum = gnum;
}

int GPIO::export_gpio()
{
        string export_str = "/sys/class/gpio/export";
        ofstream exportgpio(export_str.c_str());
        if(!(exportgpio.is_open()))
                return -1;
        exportgpio << this->gpionum;
        exportgpio.close();
        return 0;
}

int GPIO::unexport_gpio()
{
        std::string unexport_str = "/sys/class/gpio/unexport";
        ofstream unexportgpio = (unexport_str.c_str());
        if(!(exportgpio.is_open())
                return -1;
        exportgpio<<this->gpionum;
        return 0;
}

int GPIO::setdir_gpio(std::string x)
{
        std::string setdir_str = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio"+this->gpionum;+"/direction";
        ofstream setdirgpio = (setdir_str.c_str());
        if(!(setdirgpio.is_open()))
                return -1;

        if(x == "0")
        {
                setdirgpio<<"in";
        }
        if(x == "1")
                setdirgpio<<"out";
        }
        setdirgpio.close();
        return 0;
}

int GPIO::setval_gpio(std::string x)
{
        string setval_str = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio"+this->gpionum+"/value";
        ofstream setvalgpio = (setval_str.c_str());
        if(!(setvalgpio.is_open()))
                return -1;

        if(x == "0")
        {
                setvalgpio<<"0";
                setvalgpio.close();
        }
        if(x == "1")
                setvalgpio<<"1";
                setvalgpio.close();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Im trying to make a program that switches the state on my RPI3.
Im used to it on the Arduino, but not on RPI3.
If you know how to fix, then don't hesitate to write.
It is supposed to drive my garten sprinkler

Comment: You forgot to include necessary headers declaring stuff that you are using.

Comment: First few errors result from typos  (probably a result of copy/paste but not checking/fixing things correctly) in `GPIO::unexport_gpio()`.   The `=` in `ofstream unexportgpio = (unexport_str.c_str())` should be removed.     The `if()` checks a different variable.   Similar comments for the other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ofstream unexportgpio = (unexport_str.c_str());
```

should be

```
ofstream unexportgpio(unexport_str.c_str());
```

Incidentally this is an odd piece of code

```
std::string unexport_str = "/sys/class/gpio/unexport";
ofstream unexportgpio(unexport_str.c_str());
```

Why not do it the simpler way?

```
ofstream unexportgpio("/sys/class/gpio/unexport");
```

There's no need to make a `std::string` from a C string literal, only to get the C string back again.

Comment: Thanks bro! I'll try it out :)